# How can I read the logged user in my APIController?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, cross-domain-policy

in a WebAPI mvc project How can I read the logged user in my APIController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. send the credentials with the request from the client side by adding withCredentioals:true

   $.ajax({ url: ajaxURL,
   **crossDomain: true,
   xhrFields: {
           withCredentials: true
       },**
   success: function (data) { alert(data); },
   });
2. From your WebAPI server Add the following decoration to allow the cross origin request and to allow the credentioals: 
   **[EnableCors(origins: "http://YourClientServer:PORT", headers: "*",
     methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]**

SupportsCredentials  will add the header access-control-allow-credentials = true to your response

3. Now you can use the **User.Identity.Name**